Error when pip installing package requiring psycopg2-binary
I have a python package whose setup.py declares a dependency to psycopg2-binary package (among others) :
install_requires=['psycopg2-binary==2.9.9', ...]

I get the following error when trying to install it in my virtual environment :
Command
pip install --index-url https://some-region.pkg.dev/myproject/mypackage/simple/ mypackage

Error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2-binary==2.9.9 (from mypackage) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2-binary==2.9.9

However, there's no error when installing psycopg2-binary manually :
pip install psycopg2-binary==2.9.9

Once psycopg2-binary is installed I can install my package (same command as above) without any issue.
Question
Is it possible to install my package without having to install psycopg2(-binary) beforehand (I don't seem to have issues with the other required packages) ?

You provided --index-url that doesn't have psycopg2-binary so pip cannot install it. You need to give a few indices to install from:
pip install --index-url https://some-region.pkg.dev/myproject/mypackage/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple mypackage

Then pip will install from 2 indices.

Just to round up this topic, I'm wondering why psycopg2-binary was the only module that needed this extra url to be fetched ? Here's the list of modules required by my package for info :
install_requires=['psycopg2-binary==2.9.9', 'sshtunnel==0.4.0', 'PyYAML==6.0.2', 'bcrypt==4.2.0', 'cffi==1.17.0', 'cryptography==43.0.0', 'paramiko==3.4.1',      'psutil==6.0.0', 'pycparser==2.22', 'PyNaCl==1.5.0']

@rook Hard to answer without knowing the details of the Artifact repo at pkg.dev. Does it automatically proxy absent packages to pypi.org? If yes — it was probably a timeout fetching one package. If no — I don't know how all the packages were slurped from PyPI to pkg.dev; may be they were not, may be someone has uploaded some of them…

Ok would have to look deeper into that then.
